# What permission do I need to access Facebook ads pixels?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a Facebook app, and one of the things I'm trying to do is read a list of Facebook tracking pixels that are running on a user's website.

Facebook's [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website/v2.3) outline that it's relatively straightforward to do with a query to:

https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID/adspixels

However, I'm getting the following message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

I've currently got the following permissions enabled on the account:

- `ads_management`
- `ads_read`
- `manage_pages`

I can't see any other ad-related permissions available - am I missing something? Is this a restricted access feature to certain app developers or something?

Comment: What level of access do you have to the Ads API? IF it's not Standard, you can only manage a small number of accounts, and it's it's Development you need to be an admin of those accounts too

Comment: Huh... weird. The Graph API explorer app wouldn't give me access even though I'd granted the `ads_management` permission, but the app which I'm pending approval on for `ads_management` did (I'm the admin). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah the Graph API Explorer app ID isn't approved for Basic or Standard, so can't realistically be used to manage ads

Comment: @Igy just a testing misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the benefit of the rest of the community, the permission required is `ads_management`.

Apparently the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=) doesn't allow you to test the adspixels endpoint with "Graph API Explorer" app, even if you've granted it the `ads_management` permission.

To resolve this issue, just use your own app with the explorer.